# TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-views

I got an error and I'm not sure what it means:

`TypeError at / as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'employees'

admin.site.register(Employee)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from web_app.models import Employee

class EmployeeTemplateView(TemplateView):
    model = Employee.objects.all()
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'employee_view'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from web_app import routers
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from web_app.views import EmployeeTemplateView
admin.autodiscover()

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'employee', views.EmployeeTemplateView, "Employee")

urlpatterns = ['',
               url(r'^$', EmployeeTemplateView.as_view({'emp' : 'employees'})),
               ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you use register paths in router if you are not using them later?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`as_view` doesn't take positional arguments, it takes keyword arguments.

```
EmployeeTemplateView.as_view(emp='employees')
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the TypeError but now I got another error: EmployeeTemplateView() received an invalid keyword 'employee'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to pass this argument? What are you hoping to use it for?

Comment: I want to pass employees from view to template. Am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Well, yes. This has nothing to do with the template, this is passing a string from the URL to the view. If you used the correct view class to inherit from - ListView - it would pass the employees to the template automatically.

Answer (score 65):

Make sure that you put "as_view()" as such. Not "as_view". I made such a big mistake

Comment: This answer helped me

Comment: as_view() worked great. as_view() is a function and we need () for that. Tnxxx

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you are just trying to pass the `employees` variable from the view to the template, you can just send it this way:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from web_app.models import Employee

class EmployeeListView(ListView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'employees'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^$', EmployeeListView.as_view(), name="employees"),
               ]
```

Then you can use the `context_object_name` in the template as so:

**index.html**

```
<div>{% for employee in employees %} {{ employee }} {% endfor %}</div>
```